# How to return multiple json objects from azure function c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I already checked the duplicate question and tried same code but doesn't work.

I have two json serialized objects and want to return those two outputs .

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

    var httpResult = data.a;
    var sqlData = data.b;

    var matchedList = new List<dynamic>();

        var unmatchedList = new List<dynamic>();


            foreach (var itemHttp in httpResult)
            {
                foreach (var itemSql in sqlData)
                {
                    if (itemHttp.name == itemSql.tablename)
                    {
                        matchedList.Add(itemHttp);
                    }
                    else{

                        unmatchedList.Add(itemHttp.name);
                    }
                }
            }

    var jsonToReturn1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(matchedList);

    var jsonToReturn2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(unmatchedList);


     return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent( new { a= new{jsonToReturn1}, b= new {jsonToReturn2}}, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };


}
```

input used for function -

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "aaa"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "bbb"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "ccc"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "ddd"
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "id": "111",
      "tablename": "aaa"
    },
    {
      "id": "222",
      "tablename": "bbb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". My intuition for your suggested solution implies that you will return a json document with two properties `a` and `b`, which each have one property named `jsonToReturn1|2`, whose value is a string containing the json you actually want. This doesn't sound like a correct outcome, but it "works" in that it returns JSON. Is that what happens; does something else happen; if you receive an error response, what is the error? Please specify *exactly* what you expected and what you saw instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

*The first one (more preferable)*

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // ..

    var result = new
    {
        a = matchedList,
        b = unmatchedList
    };

    /* The mediaType-param with value 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType' can be omitted. */
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
  }
```

*Second one*

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // ..

    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        a = matchedList,
        b = unmatchedList
    });

    var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = content };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them to a container which can replicate the structure you want (a dictionary will do), then return the serialized container:

```
var container = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "a", matchedList},
    { "b", unmatchedList}
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container);
```